# How i can create Model or form for Django admin that not create table in database ?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-database

This technique create table in database but i don't want create table into database.

```
class Email(models.Model):
      to = models.EmailField(null = False)
      subject = models.CharField(max_length =  255,  null = False)
      message = models.TextField(max_length =  555, null = False,) 

class EmailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('to','subject','message',)

      #Here i can send emails to users. 
      def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
          #I commented this line because i don't want to store this model into database.
          #super(MyAdminView, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)


admin.site.register(Email,EmailAdmin)
```

Any other way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add new admin urls with your own customized form, view and template:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField()
    to = forms.EmailField()

    def send_email(self):
       send_mail(
             self.cleaned_data.get('subject'),
             self.cleaned_data.get('message'),
             'from@example.com',
             [self.cleaned_data.get('to')],
             fail_silently=False,
        )

class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  # You need to override an ModelAdmin
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('my_view/', self.my_view),
        ]
    return my_urls + urls

def my_view(self, request):
    if request.method == "GET":
         return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': EmailForm()}
    else:
       form = EmailForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.send_email()
          # rest of your view
# Template

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}
   <form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
   </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Please see the documentation available in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls).

Comment: But i don't want to create table in database. I need only model fields to get data and send email.

Comment: how i can access this form in admin ?

Comment: it should be available at `/admin/myapp/mymodel/my_view/ `

Comment: I don't register the SomeAdmin model. Like admin.site.register(Someadmin)

Comment: If you have any other ModelAdmin, then you can attach it.

Comment: How i can attach to other ModelAdmin ? Can you explain it ?